# Selecting Distinct Longitude and Latitude values and finding their median

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a Phonegap application using Google Maps API V3 and jQuery.

The application stores the longitude and latitude values separately in a MySQL database when a pothole is detected. What I need to do is select any values which are relatively close and would most probably be the same pothole.

Is there any way in jQuery/PHP/SQL to get values which are relatively close, find their mean-point and then use the value to continue processing some other things?

Basically what I would need is that once a particular pothole is detected 5 times, it would be charted on a Google Map. However only once this threshold is met. The difficulty is that the same pothole might be reported under slightly different longitude and latitude values, depending on the accuracy of the device reporting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you require to identify potholes near the new one the following code  can do this  in metres. It uses the [**Haversine Formula**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in a MySQL query  using POD with error checking.

$lat & $lng are the coordinates of the new pothole & $radius is the **search radius** in metres. 6378160 is the radius of the earth in metres at equator.

To ensure accuracy at this level the coordinates in the database must have at least 4 decimal places [**See Wiki**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)

**EDIT**

```
    try {
    // Prepare search statement
    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, lat, lng, cnt, ( 6378160 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS  distance FROM potholes  HAVING distance <  ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0,10");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt1->bindParam(1,$lat);
    $stmt1->bindParam(2,$lng);
    $stmt1->bindParam(3,$lat);
    $stmt1->bindParam(4,$radius);
    //Execute query
    $stmt1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt1->execute();
    if ($stmt1->rowCount()>0) {//Existing pothole 
        // fetch row
        $row = $stmt1->fetch();
        $id = $row['id'];
        $lat1 = $row['lat'];
        $lng1 = $row['lng'];
        $cnt = $row['cnt'];
        $meanLat = (($lat1*$cnt)+$lat)/($cnt+1);
        $meanLng = (($lng1*$cnt)+$lng)/($cnt+1);
        ++$cnt;
        // Prepare UPDATE statement existing pothole
        $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE  `potholes` SET  `lat` = ?,`cnt` =  ? WHERE  `potholes`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1");
        // Assign parameters
        $stmt2->bindParam(1,$meanLat);
        $stmt2->bindParam(2,$cnt);
        $stmt2->bindParam(3,$id);
        $stmt2->execute();
    //  }
    }else{//New pothole
        // Prepare INSERT statement new pothole
        $stmt3 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `potholes` (`id`, `lat`, `lng`, `cnt`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, '1')");
        // Assign parameters
        $stmt3->bindParam(1,$lat);
        $stmt3->bindParam(2,$lng);
        $stmt3->execute();

    }
echo json_encode($data);//Echo to calling page if required
}



catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error Message.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", data2c.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
 }
//Close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: This code would be used on inputting new pothole details in the database am I correct?  If I am understanding it correct it grabs the pothole details of the newly discovered pothole, compares the lat and lng with potholes already in the database, and if there are no potholes near it then the pothole details are inserted in the database.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user1809790 After reading your question again it does not meet the 5 times criteria. If this is required I wlll look into it.

Comment: If you have time/experience I would be extremely glad.  I am not really familiar with javascript/php myself, but trying to build my first mobile app :/

Comment: I assume you will have back end MySQL/PHP to do the heavy work

Comment: I have a MySQL Database and some PHP files which will act as web services which the Phonegap app will connect to

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [Haversine's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance between longitude & latitude coordinates of two given places. Based on which you can write a method to check through all values which are close / nearby to a given coordinate using a range in kms.

## Haversine Formula to calculate distance

```
$('some_element').click(function(){
    var location1 = [lat, lon] // Specify Longitude and latitude
    var location2 = [lat, lon] // Specify Longitude and latitude

    var lat1 = location1[0], lon1 = location1[1];
    var lat2 = location2[0], lon2 = location2[1];
    var earth = 6371 // Earth's Radius in Kms

    var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var nlat1 = (lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var nlat2 = (lat2) * Math.PI / 180;
    // Calculation
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(nlat1) * Math.cos(nlat2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = earth * c;
    var distance = Math.round(d*Math.pow(10,2)) / Math.pow(10,2); //Round off to 2 decimal places
    alert(distance);
});
```